# Why do I have to convert numbers into strings to get its location?

Tags: python

Why will it not print out the position of a integer/float until I have converted it to a string?
example

```
x = 123
print x[0] # error
```

To fix this I have to do

```
x = 123
print str(x)[0]
```

But why do I have to make it into a string for it to work?

Comment: Because you are using item access on a type that doesn't support it? What do you expect `x[0]` to *do*? Strings are sequences, numbers are not. Or to put it differently, what does *'get its location'* mean?

Comment: I'm trying to locate the first digit of x and only print out that number.

Comment: Then 123 is but *one representation* of the integer value. By turning it into a string, you 'capture' the representation into a series of digit characters and you then can get the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, why should this work in the first place? What is the nth index of a number; what is index 0 of the decimal number 123?

- Is it `1` because of its decimal representation?
- Is it `7` because of its hexadecimal representation (`7B`)?
- Is it `0` because of its hexadecimal representation (`0x7B`)?
- Is it `1` because of its octal representation (`173`)?
- Is it `0` because of its octal representation (`0173`)?
- Is it `1` because of its binary representation (`1111011`)
- Is it `1` because of its binary representation with the least significant bit first (`1101111`)?
- Is it `S` because that’s what `123` is in ASCII?
- …

As you can see, this is very unclear, and it does not make sense to begin with. When using the index access on a list, you get the nth element of the list. When you use the index access on a sequence, you get the nth element of the sequence. A string is a sequence of characters, so when using the index access on a string, you get the nth element of the string sequence; the nth character. A number is no sequence, only its string representation in some format is.

Comment: Thanks it all makes sense now

Answer (score 3):

123 is but *one representation* of the integer value. Python `int` values are not sequences or mappings, so `[item]` indexing has no meaning for them.

By turning the number into a string, you 'capture' the representation into a series of digit characters and you then can get the first one.

Another way to do it would be to divide by 10 until you have a number lower than 10:

```
x = 123
while x > 10:
    x //= 10

print x  # prints the number 1
```

Note that `x` then holds an `int` still, not a single-character string.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is because you have the wrong type.  Integers don't support indexing -- and I really don't think they should (they're not sequences or mappings and I can't think of any way that indexing an integer actually makes sense).

Note that there is more than one way to represent an integer as well:

```
>>> 0x7b == 123
True
```

So in this case, who is to say that `x[0]` should return `1` instead of `0` (or `7`) depending on how you want to think of it?

Answer (score 0):

As a side note to the excellent answers above, this is one way you can convert a number to a list of numbers to allow indexing:

```
In [2]: map(int,str(123))
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3]

In [3]: map(int,str(123))[0]
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: type(map(int,str(123))[0])
Out[4]: int
```